# Makefile issue - target command not excuted

Tags: makefile

I have the following makefile. When I run "make" or "make all", I get the following output:

**make all -n**

```
protoc -I protos/ --cpp_out=protos-gen/ protos//fd.proto
g++-4.9  -O4 -std=c++14 -g  -I/usr/local/include -pthread  -c -o protos-gen//fd.pb.o protos-gen//fd.pb.cc
protoc -I protos/ --grpc_out=protos-gen/ --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`which grpc_cpp_plugin` protos//fd.proto
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I protos/ --python_out=protos-gen/ --grpc_python_out=protos-gen/ protos//fd.proto
g++-4.9  -O4 -std=c++14 -g  -I/usr/local/include -pthread  -c -o protos-gen//fd.grpc.pb.o protos-gen//fd.grpc.pb.cc
```

**Issue is: I don't see the following line executed:**

```
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDE)  $(SOURCE_DIR)/fd_server_grpc.cpp $(DLIB_DIR)/dlib/all/source.cpp  -DDLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT=1  -DDLIB_PNG_SUPPORT=1 $(LIB) -lzmq -o $(BIN_DIR)/fd_server_grpc
```

**What am I missing?**

======================

```
SOURCE_DIR = src
BUILD_DIR  = build
BIN_DIR    = bin
DLIB_DIR   = ../../3rdparty/dlib/

all: $(BIN_DIR)/fd_server_grpc $(BIN_DIR)/fd_client_grpc

$(BIN_DIR)/fd_server_grpc: $(PROTOS_GEN_PATH)/fd.pb.o 
$(PROTOS_GEN_PATH)/fd.grpc.pb.o $(SOURCE_DIR)/fd_server_grpc.cpp 
$(DLIB_DIR)/dlib/all/source.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDE)  $(SOURCE_DIR)/fd_server_grpc.cpp 
$(DLIB_DIR)/dlib/all/source.cpp  -DDLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT=1  -DDLIB_PNG_SUPPORT=1 $(LIB) -lzmq -o $(BIN_DIR)/fd_server_grpc

$(BIN_DIR)/fd_client_grpc: $(PROTOS_GEN_PATH)/fd.pb.o 
$(PROTOS_GEN_PATH)/fd.grpc.pb.o $(SOURCE_DIR)/fd_client_grpc.cpp 
$(DLIB_DIR)/dlib/all/source.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDE)  $(SOURCE_DIR)/fd_client_grpc.cpp  
$(DLIB_DIR)/dlib/all/source.cpp  -DDLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT=1  -DDLIB_PNG_SUPPORT=1 
$(LIB) -lzmq -o $(BIN_DIR)/fd_client_grpc

.PRECIOUS $(PROTOS_GEN_PATH)/fd.grpc.pb.cc $(PROTOS_GEN_PATH)/fd.pb.cc:

$(PROTOS_GEN_PATH)/fd.pb.o:$(PROTOS_GEN_PATH)/fd.pb.cc
$(PROTOS_GEN_PATH)/fd.pb.cc: $(PROTOS_PATH)/fd.proto
        $(PROTOC) -I $(PROTOS_PATH) --cpp_out=$(PROTOS_GEN_PATH) $(PROTOS_PATH)/fd.proto

$(PROTOS_GEN_PATH)/fd.grpc.pb.o:$(PROTOS_GEN_PATH)/fd.grpc.pb.cc
$(PROTOS_GEN_PATH)/fd.grpc.pb.cc: $(PROTOS_PATH)/fd.proto
        $(PROTOC) -I $(PROTOS_PATH) --grpc_out=$(PROTOS_GEN_PATH) --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=$(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_PATH) $(PROTOS_PATH)/fd.proto
        python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I $(PROTOS_PATH) --python_out=$(PROTOS_GEN_PATH) --grpc_python_out=$(PROTOS_GEN_PATH) $(PROTOS_PATH)/fd.proto

clean:
        rm -f $(BUILD_DIR)/* $(BIN_DIR)/* $(PROTOS_GEN_PATH)/*
```

Comment: Does `$(BIN_DIR)/fd_server_grpc` _need_ to be made?  (i.e. does it already exist and is up-to-date?)

Comment: Your makefile is extremely strange. Maybe the result of akond's editing. Can you please edit it yourself?

Comment: I figured this out. The line $(CXX) did not start with a tab; had 8 spaces instead. Once I introduced tabs, it worked just fine. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. The line $(CXX) did not start with a tab; had 8 spaces instead. Once I introduced tabs, it worked just fine. Thanks all!